# Make a UITextView go full screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to make a UITextView go full screen. How would I implement this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very clear about your requirement.

But if you want that textview becomes as big as the view (leaving the tabbar and Navigationbar if exists) then you can simply set the frame of your textView to (0,0,320,480).

You can do this from **XIB** or you can set it **dynamically** using `IBOutlet` of your textView as shown below

```
[textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
```

Hope this helps you.

If your requirement is different then do let me know, I would be more than happy to re-structure my answer to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Parth. That's pretty much all I want. I guess I can embed it within animation loop to make it go full screen nicely. I will try this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using hard coded values for your frame I would recommend using:

```
CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[textView setFrame:r];
```

This would make your code more future proof (and work on all iOS devices).